# A specific problem finding homoclenic and heteroclenic orbits for a velocity field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

In my study of dynamical systems I just met this specific problem:

> If a 2D autonomous system is governed by the Hamiltonian $ H(x,y)= \frac{A}{k}sin(kx)sin(\pi y) $ where $ A,k $ are non zero constants. We are asked to find the homoclinic, heteroclinic and closed (periodic) orbits.
>
> Just to be clear here is the system:
>
> $ \dot{x} = -\pi\frac{A}{k}sin(kx)cos(\pi y) $
>
> $ \dot{y} = Acos(kx)sin(\pi y) $

And I was wondering if there an analytic method to do this? I cannot seem to find such a method online or in the literature, so I am in need of help on this. I thank all helpers.

Comment: Hamiltonian system is an example of conservative system. For all conservative systems holds the following: the necessary condition for having heteroclinic connection between two steady states is that the values of first integral calculated at them are the same. It's a simple combination of two facts: 1) the first integral computed along trajectory is a constant function; 2) passing to the limit $t \rightarrow \pm \infty$ tells what value first integral takes at $\alpha-$ or $\omega$-limit set. If you have two equilibria that have different first integral values then there is no heteroclinics.

Comment: However, if you have that two or more equilibria lying in the same level set of the first integral, you have to study how that level set looks like. After plotting this level set you can conclude what equilibria really have heteroclinic connections. The same step applies for finding homoclinics.